# Creating a dynamically updating list of items using a MIGX config list in MODX

Tags: php, loops, foreach, modx, migx

Please bear with me as I try to explain this. Using https://dev.bipc.com/people/ as my example, I'm trying to dynamically update the list of items in the "admissions" drop-down to only show items that are currently used by our staff.

Presently, it's just a list generated using the MIGX Loop Collection snippet:

```
[[migxLoopCollection?
    &packageName=`myPackage`
    &classname=`myClassname`
    &sortConfig=`[{"sortby":"name"}]`
    &tpl=`@CODE: <option value="[[+uid]]">[[+name]]</option>`
    &toPlaceholder = `listPlaceholder`
]]
```

However, this method shows *all items* not just ones that have been selected by users and this results in items filtering all people out and showing nothing.

Instead, I was trying to create a list using only published staff resources that I could feed into an array, remove duplicates and output a formatted line item based on the **&tpl** code above.

I started off using PDO Resources to select all parent IDs of my resources, limit the scope to 5 users for testing, define my chunk template and Template Var names.

```
[[pdoResources?
    &parents=`xxx`
    &depth=`0`
    &limit=`5`
    &tpl=`list-courtTpl`
    &includeTVs=`LastName,Admissions`
    &sortby=`{"LastName":"ASC"}`
    &toPlaceholder=`listItems`
]]

[[+listItems:removeDupsList]]
```

**list-courtTpl** only included *getImageList* to collect all the items from each resource:

```
[[getImageList?
    &tvname=`Admissions`
    &tpl=`list-CourtNameTpl`
    &docid=`[[+id]]`
]]
```

**list-CourtNameTpl** plays with the unique ids and outputs their Names only with the getCourName snippet.

```
[[+getCourtsList:getCourtName:trimWhiteSpace]]
```

The **trimWhiteSpace** snippet feeds in each Admission item and adds a double pipe separator and trim whitespace surrounding each item (which it's not doing):

```
$output = $input . "||";
echo trim($output);
```

The **removeDupsList** snippet is supposed to take the current list and explode each item into an array, remove the duplicates using *array_unique*, sort the data and output each value:

```
$list_input = explode('||', $input);
$list = array_unique($list_input);
sort($list);

$output = '';
foreach ($list as $x => $value) :
    $output .= $modx->getChunk('list-CourtItemTpl',array(
      'courtItem' => $value
    ));
endforeach;
echo $output;
```

Now here's the problem, I keep getting a string of items with spaces in between like this:

> Washington DC Florida Texas Washington DC Pennsylvania New Jersey

And you can see that the duplicate item for **Washington DC** has not been removed. I'm assuming because the first item has no space in front of it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks